# Linux Server with DynDNS - Can only access in same network, not via web

Tags: networking, firewall, dynamic-dns, linux-server, fritzbox

I want to make my Linux server accessible via Internet. I can access the Server from network via FTP (WinSCP), can connect the running MySQL Database on Port 3306 and can access the running REST-Service on Port 8080. My Problem is, that if I change the IP to the dynDNS Url, I have no access to all this ports (Connection refused).

What I did: I got an ipv6 dynamic DNS Url (xxxx.dynv6.net) and configured my FritzBox!7430. The dynDNS got the correct IPv6 updated. If I ping the dynDNS-URL, my FritzBox's IP answeres. Then I forwarded the Ports 20,21,22,3306 and 8080 to my Linux Server's IPv4 and IPv6.

[My FritzBox forwarded ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Yp0.png)

My server's firewall also allows the ports 20,21,22,3306 and 8080. This works fine, as I can connect to the server, if I am in the same Network and use the ipv4 of the server.

What am I doing wrong? Where is the point, the connection is refused? Have I to allow the server access from the internet?

I spent 3 hours on google, reading and trying. But till now, I was not able to fix it.

**Edit:**

My Problem in short:

If I take my smartphone and enter http://[xxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xxx]:8080/api/users/get/5 when it is connected to WLAN, I get the user data from database, so REST is available.
If I call the same URL when I am not in WLAN, I can not connect to the server. Also if I replace the IPv6 with the ddns (xxx.dynv6.net), I can not connect.

Do I have to configure something else to my FritzBox, to forward the request to my server?

Comment: You are running into a hairpin NAT issue. Google that - this has been answered many times here.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is another. I can not access my server via internet, also if I am in an other network. Example: I have a RESTful Service on Port 8080. If i call my server in the network via http://[2001:a62:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx:6ec8]:8080/api/users/get/5, i get the user returned from REST's database. If i call the ddns from my smartphone (not in WLAN) xxxx.dynv6.net:8080/api/users/get/5, I get an error, that the website is not reachable.